# I can't get custom data from API in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, rest, axios

ı am a beginner react native developer. I am trying to GET custom data with changing /name property at the URL. My getData() function is working without problem but when ı use getCustomData() ı am having an error. By the way, ı don't think that ı implemented the API page right. So if you have any suggestions please give me a hand.

If you want to take a look at the repo,
https://github.com/OnurSerbes/country-api-app-react-native

[image: The error]

**This is my main screen to dispaly API data**

```
import {FlatList, StyleSheet, View} from "react-native"
import CountryItem from "../components/CountryItem"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getCustomData, getData} from "../util/api";
import SearchBar from "react-native-dynamic-search-bar";



function CountriesOverviewScreen({navigation}){

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [changedData, setChangedData] = useState('');

    useEffect(()=>{
        getData(setData)
    }, []) 

    useEffect(()=>{
    if (changedData) {
          getCustomData(setData, changedData)
     }
  },[changedData])

    function renderCountryItem(itemData){

        function pressHandler(){
            navigation.navigate('CountriesDetail', {
                name: itemData.item.name,
                flag: itemData.item.flags.png,
                capital: itemData.item.capital,
                population: itemData.item.population,
                timezone: itemData.item.timezones,
                language: itemData.item.languages[0]['name'],
            })
        }
        return (
            <CountryItem
            onPress={pressHandler}
            title={itemData.item.name}
            imageUrl={itemData.item.flags.png}
            />   
        )
    }

    return  (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <SearchBar
            placeholder="Search here"
            onSearchPress = {(text)=>{setChangedData(text)}}/>
            <FlatList
            style={styles.flatlist} 
            numColumns={2}
            data={data}
            renderItem={renderCountryItem}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}/>
        </View>
    )

}

export default CountriesOverviewScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        marginTop: 15,
    },
    flatlist: {
        margin: 10,
    }
})
```

**This is the api.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

export const getData = async function(setData){
    await axios.get('https://restcountries.com/v2/all')
    .then((json)=> setData(json.data))
    .catch((e)=>{
        console.log(e)
    })
}

export const getCustomData = async function(setData, countryName){
    await axios.get(`https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${countryName}`)
    .then((json)=> setData(json.data))
    .catch((e)=>{
        console.log(e)
    }) 
}
```

**EDIT:**
ı am getting this after ı console.log(country name) in getCustomData
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the **EDIT** block ı logged the countryName and ı found that ı am not returning string, so ı changed the "SearchBar" components function.

```
onChangeText={(text) => setChangedData(text)}
onSearchPress={() => getCustomData(setData, changedData)}
```

and also ı take the getCustomData out from useEffect. I am just using it in SearchBar component

Answer (score 1):

It's a 404 error which means you are accessing the resource which is not available on the server, also in your code there is a " . " missing before then

```
export const getCustomData = async function(setData, countryName){
await axios.get(`https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${countryName}`)
then((json)=> setData(json))
.catch((e)=>{
    console.log(e)
}) 
}
```

here add . before then, something like this

```
export const getCustomData = async function(setData, countryName){
await axios.get(`https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${countryName}`)
.then((json)=> setData(json))
.catch((e)=>{
    console.log(e)
}) 
}
```

Comment: I edited the ".then" thanks for showing that, now the "promise" error is gone but 404 is still the same. I understand that it's not about me. The server just doesn't have that resource. But the documentary folder of the API still have that /name property

Answer (score 1):

the reason why is that happenning is that you are making an axios get request before the value of the useState has changed as it does not change directly.
what you can do instead is:

```
function CountriesOverviewScreen({navigation}){

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [changedData, setChangedData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(()=>{
        getData(setData)
    }, []) 

    useEffect(()=>{
    if (changedData!=null) {
        if(changedData[0]!=undefined){
          getCustomData(setData, changedData);
          }
     }
  },[changedData])

    function renderCountryItem(itemData){

        function pressHandler(){
            navigation.navigate('CountriesDetail', {
                name: itemData.item.name,
                flag: itemData.item.flags.png,
                capital: itemData.item.capital,
                population: itemData.item.population,
                timezone: itemData.item.timezones,
                language: itemData.item.languages[0]['name'],
            })
        }
        return (
            <CountryItem
            onPress={pressHandler}
            title={itemData.item.name}
            imageUrl={itemData.item.flags.png}
            />   
        )
    }

    return  (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <SearchBar
            placeholder="Search here"
            onSearchPress = {(text)=>{setChangedData([text])}}/>
            <FlatList
            style={styles.flatlist} 
            numColumns={2}
            data={data}
            renderItem={renderCountryItem}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}/>
        </View>
    )

}
```

So the changes that I suggested is creating a search state, and it only makes an axios get if the search is true, (the data will be updated by that time as well in the useState)

Edit:
I removed the setSearch and added an if statement that checks if changedData is null, if not it proceeds to search when the value is not undefined

Comment: It make sense but it didn't work... I am still having [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404] after ı click the search button. I also wanted to varify it with console.log(changedData) in the useEffect after ı use getCustomData function. It seems like everythink is null in it

Comment: You can change the data type of the initial useState to null. Then when you assign a value to it assign it as an array. then in the use effect you can make an if statement to check wether the usestate is null or not. I edited my code, and hopefully it works

Comment: Thanks for the support Johnnie, ı add an answer. The problem was about getting the resource as object not string so ı cant be able to see and it gives me 404. I understand your solution as well but the problem is not based on that, still it is a very good solution to other posible problems. Thanks for your comment.